# Getting a derived type from registered generic interface

Tags: c#, structuremap

I have a host application which provides a plugin interface that can be implemented by plugins. When initializing plugins the host app passes in the Structuremap registry so the plugin can register things

```
public interface IAppPlugin
{
    void Initialize(IRegistry configure);
}

public class CatPlugin : IAppPlugin
{
    public void Initialize(IRegistry configure)
    {
        configure.For<IFilter<IPet>>()
            .Add<CatFilter<IPet>>();
    }
}
```

In my host app I have an implementation of **IPet**, **FeralCat** and I want to get from structuremap any filters

```
ObjectFactory.TryGetInstance<IFilter<FeralCat>>
```

I was hoping this would return me the **CatFilter** filter registered by my plugin, but it doesnt (which makes sense really, I havent registered a matching type)

My plugin doesnt know about the **FeralCat**, how can I configure structuremap to return the **CatFilter** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at [Advanced StructureMap: connecting implementations to open generic types](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/12/18/advanced-structuremap-connecting-implementations-to-open-generic-types/), it might be useful in your case.

But for your specific code:

```
var container = new Container();

container.Configure(
    x =>
    {                    
        x.For(typeof(IPet)).Use(typeof(FeralCat));
        x.For(typeof(IFilter<>)).Use(typeof(CatFilter<>));
    });

var instances = container.GetAllInstances<IFilter<FeralCat>>();
```

Will give you an instance of `CatFilter<FerelCat>`.

Comment: thanks for your reply, but I have already tried that and structuremap throws an 'An item with the same key has already 
been added' error, as the argument to CatFilter is generic (although constrained) not an interface... public class CatFilter<TModel> : IFilter<TModel> where TModel : IPet

Comment: I've actually tried this in a test, defining CatFilter exactly as you did. It works. There must be something more to your code that is giving you the exception.